# form_for issue in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to Phoenix/Elixir and am trying to make a little chat app. I'm having some difficulties and hope you can help.

Here is my code

```
<%= f = form_for :chat, "#", id: "chat-form", phx_submit: :submit_message %>
  <%= text_input f, :message, placeholder: "Enter Message" %>
</form>
```

This throws the following error

```
(Phoenix.LiveView.HTMLTokenizer.ParseError) lib/chat_web/live/room_live.html.heex:13:5: unmatched closing tag. Expected </div> for <div> at line 6, got: </form>
```

Removing the closing tag presents me with the following error

```
(CompileError) lib/chat_web/live/room_live.html.heex:11: undefined function form_for/3
```

Please can someone help me find out why it isn't working

Comment: If you assign a chat changeset to your LiveView, use @chat instead of :chat

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for [`Phoenix.HTML.Form.form_for/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#form_for/3), the first argument is expected to be of [`Phoenix.HTML.FormData.t()`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.FormData.html#t:t/0) type, while you are passing an atom there.

Somewhat alongside the below lines would work.

```elixir
<%= f = form_for @changeset, "#", id: "chat-form", phx_submit: :submit_message %>
  <%= text_input f, :message, placeholder: "Enter Message" %>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the new documentation here: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#form_for/3

The new syntax looks like this:

```
<%= form_for :chat, "#", id: "chat-form", phx_submit: :submit_message, fn f -> %>
  <%= text_input f, :message, placeholder: "Enter Message" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're falling afoul (like I just did) of the fact that building forms as you are, is what's suggested by the Phoenix docs, but you're using `heex` templates which enforce that the tags in your HTML are correct.

So there's two solutions here, depending on what sort of app you're writing.

1. If you're not using LiveView, then save that template as `leex` instead, and it'll work as it.
2. If you are using LiveView then there's a new way of building these forms with a `form/1` function, documented here: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.Helpers.html#form/1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent version of phoenix_live_view, `.heex` templates are used now and it should be written like this (also don't forget to import `Phoenix.HTML.Form`):

```
<%= form_for @chat_changeset, "#",
        [id: "chat-form",
        phx_submit: :submit_message], fn f -> %>
   <%= text_input f, :message, placeholder: "Enter Message" %>
<% end %>
```